# Get angle into range 0 - 2*pi - python

Tags: python, mapping, phase

In my simulation i compute multiple values for a phase, for example

```
phi = np.linspace(-N,N,1000)
```

where N can be large.

Is there an easy way to map the values to the intervall [0,2pi) ?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand but why don't you just use the result of modulo 2*pi on phi ?

Comment: I tried  _ phi % 2*pi _ or _ 2*pi % phi _ but i does not work. The Transformation is not correct

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Does that work ?

```py
import numpy as np
import math

N=10
phi = np.linspace(-N,N,1000)

phi = phi%(2*math.pi)

print(phi)
```

Output

```
[2.56637061 2.58639063 ... 3.69679467 3.71681469]
```

Comment: I found my mistake. Instead of phi = phi%(2*math.pi) i used phi = phi % 2*math.pi..... Thx for your fast answer!

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are looking for [np.interp](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html). Scipy offers an [interpolate](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html#scipy.interpolate.interp1d) function too.

For a usage example, to map the values of phi (which are between -N and N) to [0, 2π] try

```
np.interp(phi, (-N, N), (0, 2*np.pi))
```

To exclude 2π you could either change upper bound so no value maps onto 2π.

```
np.interp(phi, (-N, N + 1), (0, 2*np.pi))
```

Or reduce the largest value you include in phi

```
phi = np.linspace(-N, N, 1000, endpoint=False)
```

---

I believe it would be easier to just ask for the values directly.

For example, 1000 points over the range [0, 2π] can be given by

```
np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 1000)
```

And for the range [0, 2π) which excludes the value 2π

```
np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 1000, endpoint=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible way:

First, convert to the [-pi, pi] interval using `np.arctan2(np.sin(angle), np.cos(angle))`. Then, you still need to transform the negative values. A final function like this would work:

```
 def convert_angle_to_0_2pi_interval(angle):
    new_angle = np.arctan2(np.sin(angle), np.cos(angle))
    if new_angle < 0:
        new_angle = abs(new_angle) + 2 * (np.pi - abs(new_angle))
    return new_angle
```

To confirm, run:

```
angles = [10, 200, 365, -10, -180]
print(np.rad2deg([convert_angle_to_0_2pi_interval(np.deg2rad(a)) for a in angles]))
```

...which prints: [ 10., 200., 5., 350., 180.]

Comment: This is actually the preferrable approach, in general. Though https://stackoverflow.com/a/58628109/7084566 can be adjusted to all kind of cases and intervals (leftopen, rightopen, lower, upper) it gets rather unhandy for spherical coordinates, lest to talk of hyper-spherical coordinates.
Instead, it is easier to convert to Euclidean coordinates and then back to (hyper-)spherical ones.